# Recursively Drawing Circles

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to draw this:
[image]

```
public void drawCircle(int x, int y, int diameter, int it) {
    int d = diameter / 3;
    if (it == 0) {
        return;
    }
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillOval(x, y, d, d);
    drawCircle(x, y, d, it--); // centre
    drawCircle(x - d, y, d, it--); // left
    drawCircle(x + d, y, d, it--); // right

}
```

For the purposes of this question, ignore the actual positions of the where I draw the circles - I will change this later as it's not quite right. However, where am I going wrong within the logic of my program? For me, it seems clear I am calling the method to draw three circles every iteration.  Here is my error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.java2d.loops.ProcessPath.ProcessMonotonicCubic(Unknown Source)
at sun.java2d.loops.ProcessPath.ProcessCubic(Unknown Source)
at sun.java2d.loops.ProcessPath.doProcessPath(Unknown Source)
at sun.java2d.loops.ProcessPath.fillPath(Unknown Source)
at sun.java2d.pipe.BufferedRenderPipe.fillPath(Unknown Source)
at sun.java2d.pipe.BufferedRenderPipe.fill(Unknown Source)
at sun.java2d.pipe.BufferedRenderPipe.fillOval(Unknown Source)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.fillOval(Unknown Source)
at Draw.drawCircle(Draw.java:40)
at Draw.drawCircle(Draw.java:41)
```

Here are lines 40 and 41:

```
g.fillOval(x, y, d, d);
drawCircle(x, y, d, it--); // centre
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your recursive call receives the same value of `it` during each recursive call, because `it--` returns the value of `it` before it decrements.

Assuming you want to keep the value of `it` intact throughout one iteration, just pass `it - 1` to the recursive call, e.g.

```
drawCircle(x, y, d, it - 1); // centre
```

Comment: `it--` returns the value of it and then remove 1; `--it` removes 1 and then returns the value.